# How do I set the height of the SLIME REPL?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

When I start SLIME (`M-x slime`), the SLIME REPL window takes up the bottom half of the frame. Is there a setting for changing the default height of the REPL? I want the REPL window to take up less than half of the height of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

In emacs you may use [fit-window-to-buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Resizing-Windows.html#index-fit_002dwindow_002dto_002dbuffer) and call it (or a function using it) from a hook:

```
(defun flux-fit-slime-repl ()
  ;; uncomment the following line:
  ;; (interactive)
  ;; if you want to call
  ;; flux-fit-slime-repl yourself to experiment
  (fit-window-to-buffer))

(add-hook 'slime-connected-hook 'flux-fit-slime-repl 'append)
```

The final argument to [add-hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Hooks.html#index-add_002dhook) above, `append`, asks that this hook be placed at the end of the slime-connected hooks as we want slime to be done printing the welcome before we resize.

If you'd rather call `fit-window-to-buffer` from the lisp side, you could
allow swank to send code to emacs by customizing `slime-enable-evaluate-in-emacs` in emacs prior to calling this in the slime repl:

```
(swank::eval-in-emacs '(swank-io-package::fit-window-to-buffer))
```

Add the line above to [`~/.swank.lisp`](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Lisp_002dside.html) in order to have it evaluated when slime starts.

Comment: I had previously written an answer, but did not understand when the `slime-connected-hook` runs, so I didn't use it; that's a good trick to know. I have rewritten and undeleted my answer to use this hook with a couple of other options for the resizing. Thanks for the tip +1

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the size of the REPL window instead of making it as small as possible by making use the `slime-connected-hook` in the way described by @chrnybo, but then using `window-resize` to reduce the window size. Since you can't vertically resize a window that is full-height in the frame, you should check to see that it is either at the top or at the bottom (but not both). Add the code below to your `.emacs` file to create Slime REPL windows that are 10 lines smaller than the default:

```
(defun my-reduced-slime-repl ()
  (when (xor (window-at-side-p 'nil 'bottom)
             (window-at-side-p 'nil 'top))
    (window-resize 'nil -10)))

(add-hook 'slime-connected-hook 'my-reduced-slime-repl 'append)
```

Here is another version that will make the REPL window `*my-slime-repl-height*` lines tall, unless the specifed height is larger than the default, in which case the default height is retained:

```
(defvar *my-slime-repl-height* 10)

(defun my-reduced-slime-repl ()
  (let* ((win-height (window-total-height))
         (delta (- *my-slime-repl-height* win-height)))
    (when (and (< delta 0)
               (xor (window-at-side-p 'nil 'bottom)
                    (window-at-side-p 'nil 'top)))
      (window-resize 'nil delta))))

(add-hook 'slime-connected-hook 'my-reduced-slime-repl 'append)
```